# how to make mobx store in single spa application root-config to share data and state among all micro applications?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, micro-frontend, single-spa

I am newbie in microfrontends. I am currently using single-spa framework.I have learnt micro frontend applications creation and integration but i am facing problems in sharing data,UI common components and state between micro applications.Can anyone explain these processes using mobx or any other solution or library?

I searched on youtube and google but i did not get anything.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, your question is too broad to cater an acceptable answer.  Still, I'll volunteer this one.

The `single-spa` library (it is not a framework) has nothing to do with state, so there is no provision to that effect.  What you *can* find in it, is mechanisms to pass props to your components.

Now, armed with this knowledge, you can start investigating how to share state between micro-frontends according to what's possible with your state management library.  Remember that `single-spa` doesn't favor a particular framework or library so its concepts remain agnostic.  Whether you use mobx, Redux, Svelte stores, Pinia or anything else, is out of the scope of `single-spa`.

Now, **personally**, I do Svelte and use Svelte stores.  Stores can be passed via props, so it is very straightforward to share state between micro-frontends, even if they aren't Svelte because Svelte stores can be easily consumed from React, Vue, Solid or any other.